# Changing the gradient effect on uibutton in highlighted state ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, gradient

I m trying to implement a linear gradient effect on uibutton through code.

The button color lightens at the top side in default state.
On TouchDown, this effect moves to the bottom of the button.
after pressing is over, it again gets back to default state.

I really appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved this by creating the different images for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateHighlighted. And then setting them:
`[button1 setBackgroundImage:backgroundImageStretched forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:backgroundImagePressedStretched forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

Is this what your are looking for i can post a more detailed example?

Comment: Sorry, but i m luking to do it through code.